# Page has horizontal scroll bar, despite being a finite width

Tags: html, css, browser

On [this page](http://www.idyldesign.com/index.php) the width is 1100px, however on IE, occasionally Google Chrome (randomly as far as I can tell) and always on the iPad, there is a horizontal scroll bar leading to nothing. I can't establish why as th body and every other element has a width. I would copy in the code, but see that as a little excessive considering the easiest way to diagnose this is to "inspect element"

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Ok. Will add code when I am in front of the machine nt iPad later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First resolve the javascript error you've got on the page..

Anyway you can add to your css:

```
body { 
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: And what if the website doesn't fit into the user's viewport?

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome, for me, setting `background-size:100%;` for body, solved the problem! Try!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this property from the body:

background-attachment: fixed;

This should resolve the issue.

overflow: hidden; will remove all the scroll bars from your website, and it will cause some arrangement issues.